# Why do I get such output from this simple Go code?

Tags: go

I am new to Go and very confused with one of the sample codes in the tutorial. Here is the code and its output:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func pow(x, n, lim float64) float64 {
    if v := math.Pow(x, n); v < lim {
        return v
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%g >= %g\n", v, lim)
    }
    return lim
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(pow(3, 3, 10), pow(4, 3, 20))
}
```

When I run it, the output of this code is:

```
27 >= 10
64 >= 20
10 20
```

Which is quite strange to me! I expect this output:

```
27 >= 10
10
64 >= 20
20
```

Can someone please help me to understand what is going on with Println in this code?

Comment: The functions run both before Println is called.

Comment: To clarify on tkausl's comment: when method is called, all arguments are evaluated, and only then call is made. Here this means calling both your `pow` funcs (and triggering their side-effects) and only __then__ printing their results.

Comment: Evaluation order is specified [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Order_of_evaluation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Go, as in the vast majority of modern programming languages, the arguments of a function call are evaluated before the function call itself. Consider the following function:

```
func add(i, j int) int {
  return i + j
}
```

And let's call it like this:

```
func a() int {
  return 2
}

func b() int {
  return 3
}

// ... somewhere in main()
add(a(), b())
```

You would expect that, by the time the code of `add` runs, the values of `i` and `j` are known, right? The call would then return `5` as expected. To enable this, the Go compiler arranges for the arguments of `add` - namely `a()` and `b()` to be run before `add` itself runs.

---

The same happens in your code sample with `Println` and `pow`. The arguments to `Println` need to be evaluated before its body is run, and evaluating `pow` causes other things to be printed.